# While Loop till number reached

Tags: php

I want to do something like this

```
$x = 630;
$y = 10;

while ($y < $x){
// do something
$y+10;
}
```

When I use `$y++` it's working and adding +1, but with +10 it's not working. But I need to go in +10 steps. Any pointers ?

Comment: You have to assign the value back to the variable. The `++` is a special operator which is the same as `$y = $y + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code, you are not incrementing `$y` : `$y+10` returns the value of `$y` plus `10`, but you need to assign it to `$y`.

You can do it with several ways :

- `$y = $y + 10;`
- `$y += 10;`

Example :

```
$x = 630;
$y = 10;
while ($y < $x){
    // do something
    $y = $y + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because $y++ is equivalent to $y = $y + 1;  You are not assigning the new value in $y.  Please try

```
$y += 10;
```

OR

```
$y = $y + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// commenting the code with description
$x = 630; // initialize x
$y = 10;  // initialize y

while ($y < $x){ // checking whether x is greater than y or not. if it is greater enter loop
// do something
$y = $y+10; // you need to assign the addition operation to a variable. now y is added to 10 and the result is assigned to y. please note that $y++ is equivalent to $y = $y + 1
}
```